# Команда chown и username с точкой

Tags: linux

Можно ли командой `chown` изменить владельца файла на пользователя, имя которого содержит точку `'.'`?

Я знаю способ с uid, но меня он не устраивает, по определенным причинам, нужно именно имя. Проблема в том, что POSIX интерпретирует точку, как разделитель пользователя и группы (это устаревший стандарт, по стандарту нужно двоеточие, но тем не менее поддерживается), поэтому команда

```
chown user.name:groupname somefile
```

не срабатывает с ошибкой:

```
unknown user/group user:name:groupname
```

Экранирование точки слэшами/кавычками не работает также.

Comment: в первом примере у вас есть точка, а во втором вместо точки уже двоеточие.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вторая строчка - не пример, это результат выполнения первой команды. И там нет ошибки, все дело именно в том, что точка заменяется на двоеточие.

Comment: операционная система у вас какая? в *gnu* с программой `chown` из пакета *coreutils* — всё в порядке: отлично обращается с пользователями и группами, содержащими точки в именах.

Comment: да, у вас явно не *gnu*: там `chown` формулирует сообщение, немного по-другому: *chown: invalid user: ...*

Comment: Вы правы. Это synology и ash. И в стандарной Убунту действительно все работает.

Comment: оболочка-то (в данном случае) роли не играет (как, впрочем, и ядро), а вот операционная система там наверняка урезанная. какой-нибудь *busybox*.

Comment: Еще как урезанная, к сожалению. Самое печальное, что не работает man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chown $(id -u пользователь.с.точкой):группа somefile`

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению это не совсем то, что мне было нужно, но это абсолютно верный ответ на поставленный вопрос. Просто корень реальной проблемы был в другом, выяснилось, что меня устроило бы и просто uid. Еще раз спасибо, в любом случае, информация весьма полезна.